# Expanding a sum without evaluating it

Tags: output-formatting, formatting, summation, hold

I am currently trying to expand a sum without evaluating it, e.g.
$$\sum_{i=0}^5 i^2 = 1^2+2^2+3^2+4^2+5^2$$
So I am trying to create a function

`SumExpansion[expr_, {i_, a_, b_}]`

which outputs something like the example on the right hand side, without actually evaluating the sum. I have tried several different approaches but Mathematica always seems to evaluate it.

Answer (score 11):

may be

```
Sum[With[{i=i},HoldForm[i^2]],{i,1,5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But this uses a wrapper. I do not think there is a way without using `Hold` and friends.

Answer (score 7):

What about this? I am assuming that `expr` will be in terms of `i`:

```
SumExpansion[expr_, {a_, b_}] := HoldForm[Sum[expr, {i, a, b}]] == 
Part[Trace@(Plus @@ (Function[u, Defer@expr /. i -> u][#] & /@ 
    Range[a, b])), 3]

SumExpansion[i^2, {4, 8}]
```

> $$\sum _{i=4}^8 i^2=4^2+5^2+6^2+7^2+8^2$$

```
SumExpansion[i^2 + i + 4/i^3, {1, 5}]
```

> $$\sum _{i=1}^5
>    \left(\frac{4}{i^3}+i+i^2\right)=\left(\frac{4}{1^3}+1+1^2\right)+\left(\frac{4}{2^3}+
>    2+2^2\right)+\left(\frac{4}{3^3}+3+3^2\right)+\left(\frac{4}{4^3}+4+4^2\right)+\left(\frac{4}{5^3}+5+5^2\right)$$